# Invalidating women from the priesthood and from terumah

Tags: women, kohen-priest, mishna, teruma

In [Yevamot 6:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%95_%D7%91), we are told that one who has sexual intercourse with various types of women will "invalidate" them. The language is as follows:

> וכן הבא על אחת מכל העריות שבתורה או פסולות כגון אלמנה לכהן גדול, גרושה
>   וחלוצה לכהן הדיוט, ... בת ישראל לממזר ולנתין - פסל
>
> So too, one who has sexual intercourse with any of the *'arayot* or with invalid women - such as a high priest
>   with a widow, a regular priest with a divorcee or a *chalutzah*, a
>   mamzer or a *netin* with an Israelite girl - he invalidates [her].

Rav Ovadiah of Bertinoro interprets the reference to invalidation as relating to her subsequent inability to marry a kohen, but recognises that this only goes for the first part of the mishna and for the final example given in the second part, since a divorcee and a *chalutzah* are already invalidated from marrying kohanim. His solution is that, in the event that they were the daughters of kohanim, they are now invalidated from consuming *terumah*:

> וגרושה נמי, אי בת כהן היא מפסלה בהך ביאה מתרומה דבי נשא
>
> And a divorcee [and *chalutzah*] likewise, if she is the daughter of a
>   kohen she is invalidated by this sexual intercourse from the *terumah*
>   of her father's house.

The Mishna in [Yevamot 7:5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%96_%D7%94), however, is clear that a woman who was raped or seduced by a kohen will be unable to eat *terumah* (such as would have been permissible had she married him), but that if she was the daughter of a kohen and she was either raped or seduced by an Israelite, **she will be able to continue eating it**. The precise language is האונס והמפתה... לא פוסלים ולא מאכילים.

Unless we posit a contradiction between these two mishnayot (ie: Yevamot 6:2 is according to one *tana* and Yevamot 7:5 is according to another), we seem to have a problem. The mishna in 6:2 cannot be speaking about rape and it cannot be speaking about seduction, since the mishna in 7:5 presents a contrary halakha. We are forced to suggest that it is speaking of marriage. But the first part of the mishna (in which a man has sexual intercourse with *'arayot*) cannot concern marriage, since there is no kiddushin when it comes to *'arayot*, and the final example in the mishna also cannot be speaking about marriage, since there is no kiddushin by mamzerim and *netinim*.

Do these mishnayot contradict one another, or is there a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. In 7:5 it's talking about where the union was otherwise possible, but in 6:2 it's where the union was not otherwise possible. 7:5 even continues that they do not פוסל, but if the union was illicit, then they are פוסל.

Comment: I don't think so - the continuation of 7:5 is to the effect that those who are unfit to enter the congregation are פוסל - but that's not inclusive of divorcees and *chalutzot*.

Comment: Would you agree that a Bat Kohein (who is not a Gerusha) who is raped by a Kohein can eat Teruma bc of her father even as she gains no new permission or disqualification from having been raped by a Kohein? But a Bat Kohein Gerusha who is raped by a Kohein can no longer eat Teruma bc of her father as she is now a Chalala.